# Selecting multiple timestamps between multiple start and end times from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have two tables:

```
+----------------+        +----------------------+
|data_raw        |        |label                 |
+----------------+        +----------------------+
|type (char)     |        |serial (bigint)       |
|time (timestamp)|        |start_time (timestamp)|
|data (bigint)   |        |end_time (timestamp)  |
|serial (bigint) |        |label (text)          |
|device (text)   |        +----------------------+
+----------------+
```

I need to get all rows in data_raw where the timestamp is between the start_time and end_time in all the rows of data_label and the serial is the same. I tried,

```
 SELECT time, data FROM data_raw WHERE time BETWEEN 
 (SELECT start_time FROM label) AND 
 (SELECT end_time FROM label);
```

but this wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a join.  My postgre is rough, but I think this should do what you need:

```
SELECT time, data
FROM data_raw, label
WHERE data_raw.serial = label.serial 
AND time BETWEEN label.start_time AND label.end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I would suggest something like this.  Are you looking for this information based on a specific label?  If that's the case, That's where you'd swap out where I put 1.

```
WITH one_label AS (
SELECT * FROM label WHERE serial = 1)
SELECT time, data FROM data_raw 
WHERE time BETWEEN one_label.start_time AND one_label.end_time;
```

Comment: A "label" is just two time stamps and a label describing a span of time in data_raw where the serial in data_raw == serial in data_label. Essentially I'm trying to grab all the "labeled" data from data_raw for use in training a classification model.